# Positioning text elements to right and left of container which stretches to contain them

Tags: html, css, position

How can I position some information in a `div` to the left and right? I imagine float is involved, which lead me to the below code. `.greybottom` doesn't seem to acknowledge they exist, the height of `.greybottom` isn't big enough to contain the floated text.

```css
.purplehead {
    background-color: #A971A9;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
.greybottom {
    padding: 15px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    border: solid black 3px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
.lefttext {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.righttext {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="purplehead">Title</div>
<div class="greybottom">
    <div class="lefttext">
        lorem<br/>
        ipsum<br/>
        dolor
    </div>
    <div class="righttext">
        <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <tr>
                <td>some data</td>
                <td>some data</td>
                <td>some data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>some data</td>
                <td>some data</td>
                <td>some data</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

While using float, how can I make it such that a parent `div`'s height will include the floated children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix).

```
.greybottom::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
```

```css
.purplehead {
    background-color: #A971A9;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
.greybottom {
    padding: 15px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    border: solid black 3px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
.lefttext {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.righttext {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}

.greybottom::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="purplehead">Title</div>
<div class="greybottom">
    <div class="lefttext">
        lorem<br/>
        ipsum<br/>
        dolor
    </div>
    <div class="righttext">
        <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <tr>
                <td>some data</td>
                <td>some data</td>
                <td>some data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>some data</td>
                <td>some data</td>
                <td>some data</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```